# Chart JS - Get the points on which the line chart has traversed on a plane

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, chart.js, frontend

I would like to get the points on plane on which the ChartJS scatter chart's line has traversed.

For example, I build a line graph with this data

```
[
    {x: 0, y: 12}, 
    {x: 1, y: 14},
    {x: 2, y: 16},
    {x: 3, y: 18}
]
```

I want to know all the coordinates the line had touched, like 
*[ (x, y), (0, 12), (0.2, 12.2), (0.3, 12.4)..., (1.1, 14.1)... ]* etc.

Picture for illustration
[image]

Requirement, I would like to get the coordinates of the orange points that the graph has intersected.
[image]

I've searched for this option but didn't find it unfortunately. Any help/response is appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that shows the chart you currently have?

Comment: I have added a screenshot.

Comment: So to be clear, you're looking for the intersections of the line and the grid?

Comment: No, not the grid but the orange points that I've given in screenshot 2.

Comment: What is your actual goal? Find equidistant points on a given path?

Comment: Yes. I want to get all the points that lie on the line, equidistant, it'll be.